# How do I convert syntax " " to ' '?

Tags: xml, xslt, input, replace

Hey guys I'm having a problem in production.

I have a couple of Forms where are a lot of input fields where is up to the customer what he puts in.
I'm using [xslt](/questions/tagged/xslt) and later on java to pass all the info but right now it's all about XSLT.

You see the problem starts with this when the customer puts " " " " in the field.

So heres a just a little snippet:

```
<xh:div class="row">
    <xh:div class="col-md-12 col-sm-6 m-b-sm">
        <form:caption href="OpinionRequest_1" />
        <form:textArea id="OpinionByRequest" ref="Answer/@OpinionByRequest" />
    </xh:div>
</xh:div>
```

So whenever a customer enters some info into the field
it is later on saved in attribute OpinionByRequest.

What I want to change is whenever the customer enters this " into the field I want it to change to ' because later on I get an error because the field contains ".

I tried using `replace()` function but it gets me nowhere.

Comment: If `"` is invalid for your application, don't accept it at all. Don't change the data the user entered. But, `"` can be normally stored in XML (sometimes it needs to be encoded as an entity, but that's transparent). Are you sure you treat the value correctly everywhere (i.e. not creating the XML by string concatenation)?

Comment: yes Im sure. Theres no concatenation anywhere Im just passing this value to the next process and like 15 processes later I get an error because of that attribute contains ". It looks like this: `<Legal OpinionByRequest="bla bla something and "this is important" and then bla bla "again" ." />` you see what I mean?

Comment: That's exactly what I thought. That means something concatenates the string, otherwise it would be `OpinionByRequest="blah blah something and &quot;this is important&quot; and blah"`. That's the way how XML stores double quotes in double quoted attribute values.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere on its journey from the user input form to the XML document, the quotes need to be escaped as `&quot;`. There are other characters that need to be escaped as well, including `<` and `&`. This clearly isn't happening, but without detailed knowledge of the steps in this journey, we can't really advise where you need to make a change.

A failure to escape special characters usually means that the application is constructing XML "by hand" (using string concatenation) rather than by using a library that does the job properly. It's surprisingly common for this to happen within a third-party software product: some product vendors think they can add XML export capability as an add-on without really understanding what they are doing, or testing it thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

Something's wrong with the code. XML can handle double quotes in attributes just fine. And both Java and xslt can help you with that.

```java
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import org.w3c.dom.Attr;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;

public class testxml {

    public static void main(String argv[]) {

        try {
            Document doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()
                .newDocumentBuilder()
                .newDocument();

            Element rootElement = doc.createElement("root");
            doc.appendChild(rootElement);

            Attr attr = doc.createAttribute("attr");
            attr.setValue("blah \"blah\" blah");
            rootElement.setAttributeNode(attr);

            TransformerFactory.newInstance()
                .newTransformer()
                .transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(System.out));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><root attr="blah &quot;blah&quot; blah"/>
```

And similarly in xslt:

1.xml:

```xml
<root/>
```

1.xslt:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:attribute name="attr">
        <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Command:

```sh
xsltproc --stringparam text 'blah "blah" blah' 1.xslt 1.xml
```

Output:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root attr="blah &quot;blah&quot; blah"/>
```